# Added Facebook testers (real users) to my app but they can't login using neither JS nor PHP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am building a FB web app using PHP (with javascript to log in for the first time and PHP for renewing tokens). The app works for me as an admin, app is almost finished and I am adding my friends - testers.

However the problem is that if I add my friends as testers at Facebook Dev Dashboard, they can't use the login button on my website. Javascript doesn't do anything when they click on the button and when I tried to do a workaround by removing login JS (therefore using pure PHP login API) it didn't redirect them to facebook either.

When I made one of my tester friends an admin of my page, he suddenly could log in to my app.

Could you please help me with adding my friends as testers?

**EDIT:** Nevermind, facebook must have short circuited for a day, now it finally works as intended. I didn't change anything to make it work.